# php-fpm only accept ipv6

Tags: php, nginx

I have php-fpm
which has this setting.

```
[global]
daemonize = no

[www]
listen = 9000

[global]
error_log = /proc/self/fd/2

log_limit = 8192

[www]
; if we send this to /proc/self/fd/1, it never appears
access.log = /proc/self/fd/2

clear_env = no

catch_workers_output = yes
decorate_workers_output = no
```

However after fpm starts, it accepts only `ipv6`

```
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Why does this happen? how can I do the setting for accepting `curl 127.0.0.1:9000`

Comment: It's it the webserver that determines which IP protocol to react to?

Comment: So set the listen setting for what you want. https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#listen

Comment: Why not to set listening interface explicitly as `listen 127.0.0.1:9000`?